# File Tailing not working using TailerListenerAdapter of Apache Commons io

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-io, apache-tailer

I want to tail file contents using Java.I tried using Tailer and TailerListenerAdapter of Apache commons io. I have included storm-core-1.1.1.jar in the classpath for the required dependencies.Program compiles and runs; But the 'handle' method of TailerListenerAdapter is not called at all and the execution gets stuck inside the main method.Following is the code:

```
import org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListenerAdapter;
import org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer;
import org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListener;

import java.io.File;
public class LogTailTest {

    /**
     * TailerListener implementation.
     */
    static public class ShowLinesListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void handle(String line) {
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("inside handle");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        TailerListener listener  = new ShowLinesListener();
        File file = new File("C:/LogFiles/Radius-log");
        System.out.println("inside main");
        Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(file, listener);
        tailer.run();

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the execution stays in the main method, then it at least means that it did not crash.
You can get further insight what is happening by implementing other methods of `TailerListener` interface in your show `ShowLinesListener`. There are methods to handle file being not present, file rotationg, generic exceptions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call "tailer.run()" directly.  Instead do:

```
TailerListener listener  = new ShowLinesListener();
File file = new File("C:/LogFiles/Radius-log");
System.out.println("inside main");
Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(file, listener);
Thread thread = new Thread(tailer);
thread.setDaemon(true); // optional
thread.start();
```